# How to open image editor automatically in Greenshot?

Tags: image-editing

I am a long-time user of Greenshot and I find it very useful. However, I encountered a problem with the Image Editor on my new work laptop.

When I capture a screen shot, the Image Editor does not launch automatically. I have checked the settings and made sure that Copy to clipboard, Open in image editor, and Save as are selected, but it still does not work.

The only workaround I found is to keep the preferences dialog box open while taking screen shots. This is very inconvenient and frustrating. I have tried reinstalling Greenshot but it did not solve the issue. I would be grateful if anyone could offer some advice on how to fix this.

[image: Destination Configuration]

Comment: There is information about this issue in this Greenshot Document. See if it assists you.    https://getgreenshot.org/help/#settings

Comment: Have you spoken with your work's IT department? As they manage this computer they may be applying policies that prevent the normal behavior you're expecting. They also are responsible for making sure your computer functions to your employment needs.

Comment: Can you include screenshots of the Preferences screens of Greenshot. I'm also a user of it and I would like to compare, especially the tab of Destination. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @music2myear, yes I had to include them to remove and reinstall.  They did do some highlevel evaluation, but closed out my request with, "we don't support external software, you should reach out to the applications support team"

Comment: @harrymc - I just updated the questions with an image of the preferences for destination.

Comment: I just updated the hot key for the Capture region option, which is the one I use all the time, and that appears to have corrected my issue.  I was using the Print Screen key and changed it to a different key option.  I'll reboot system and use for a couple of days to see if it did correct my issue.